# Testing FHIR API on a public test server

Tags: testing, server, hapi-fhir

I managed to develop a FHIR API using HAPI-FHIR, now I wanted it to test to a public server, how do I upload it to the server? I want to test its interoperability between to terminals. I want to see if the other terminal can retrieve the data uploaded by the other terminal.

For example, I want to test it on http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/, how do I upload it there?

Answer (score 0):

FHIR specification does not provide exact instructions how to move data from one FHIR server into another (because it depends). You can write integration app, which will take data from one server and put into another.  There is brand new [Bulk API](https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/fhir-bulk-data-docs) to get all the data from FHIR server, but not yet Bulk-In API :)

As well we (health samurai) are forcing idea of use **transaction log API** for Server2Server real time integration (replication).